# getIfPresent caffeine return null

Tags: java, spring, caching, caffeine

```
@Autowired
Cache<Object, Object> caffeineCache; 

private void saveRequestToStorage(String key, Object value) {
 caffeineCache.put(key, value);
}

public Object getObjectFormInStorage(String key) {
return Optional.ofNullable(caffeineCache.getIfPresent(key)).orElseThrow(()
        -> new MbNotFoundException("error.msg.request.storage.not.found"));
}
```

i put value to cache in method 1 and get it in method 2 but method return null with same key in method 1.
Anyone can help me?

Below is config

```
@Bean
public Caffeine caffeineCacheBuilder(LocalCacheConfigurationProperties properties) {
    return Caffeine.from(properties.getCaffeine().getSpec());
}

@Bean
public Cache<Object, Object> caffeineCache(Caffeine caffeineCacheBuilder) {
    return caffeineCacheBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public CacheManager localCacheManager(Caffeine caffeineCacheBuilder, LocalCacheConfigurationProperties properties) {
    CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(properties.getCacheNames())) {
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(null); // dynamic
    } else {
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(Arrays.asList(properties.getCacheNames()));
    }
    cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with Spring, but sounds like you have a prototype bean rather than a singleton. Are you sure its the same instance on each request?

Comment: yeah, i sure that. This bean has default scope => bean is singleton.

Comment: What is the cache configuration? For example weakKeys is reference equality so a different instance wouldn’t match.

Comment: app.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=10000, expireAfterWrite=20s, recordStats, weakKeys, weakValues

Comment: i remove weakKeys, weakValues then cache  has been run correctly. Thanks!

Comment: So weak keys is the culprit and you likely don’t need weak references anyway.

Answer (score 0):

the configuration is a bit strange.. try this

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-caffeine-cache